# Spring AMQP transacted channel deadlock

Tags: java, spring-transactions, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I have a requirement to send a message to a RabbitMQ instance with a JPA entity after persisting/flushing it, which lead me to configure the `rabbitTemplate` as `channelTransacted`.

The consumer is external, but, to create an integration test, I have added an embedded broker (Apache QPid) and a listener to be able to check that the messages are sent.

As indicated by the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/#_blocked_connections_and_resource_constraints), I seem to have ran into a deadlock:

> If we have producers and consumers in the same application, we may end up with a deadlock when producers are blocking the connection (because there are no resources on the Broker any more) and consumers cannot free them (because the connection is blocked). [...]
>
> A separate CachingConnectionFactory is not possible for **transactional** producers that execute on a consumer thread, since they should reuse the Channel associated with the consumer transactions.

If I set `rabbitTemplate.channelTransacted = false`, the listener gets invoked fine, otherwise `harness.getNextInvocationDataFor` just waits until it times out.

What I'm hoping is that there's still a way to do this kind of integration test and that perhaps I configured something wrong.

I've tried with both the `simple` and the `direct` listener types, didn't make any difference:

```
queues:
  transactions: 'transactions'

spring:
  rabbitmq:
    host: rabbitmq
    username: guest
    password: guest

    dynamic: true # automatically create queues and exchanges on the RabbitMQ server
    template:
      routing-key: ${queues.transactions}
      retry.enabled: true
      # mandatory: true # interesting only for cases where a reply is expected

    # publisher-confirms: true # does not work in transacted mode
    publisher-returns: true # required to get notifications in case of send problems

    # used for integration tests
    listener:
      type: direct
      direct:
        retry:
          enabled: true
          stateless: false # needed when transacted mode is enabled
          max-attempts: 1 # since this is used just for integration tests, we don't want more
```

I'm using Spring Boot 2.1.3 with the `spring-boot-starter-amqp`, which pulls in `spring-rabbit-2.1.4` and Apache Qpid 7.1.1 as the embedded broker for the test:

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(properties = "spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true")
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase
@Transactional
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class SalesTransactionGatewayTest {

    private static final String TRANSACTIONS_LISTENER = "transactions";

    @TestConfiguration
    @RabbitListenerTest(spy = false, capture = true)
    public static class Config {
        @Bean
        public SystemLauncher broker() throws Exception {
            SystemLauncher broker = new SystemLauncher();
            Map<String, Object> attributes = new HashMap<>();
            attributes.put(SystemConfig.TYPE, "Memory");
            attributes.put(SystemConfig.INITIAL_CONFIGURATION_LOCATION, "classpath:qpid-config.json");
            attributes.put(SystemConfig.STARTUP_LOGGED_TO_SYSTEM_OUT, false);
            broker.startup(attributes);
            return broker;
        }

        @Bean
        public Listener listener() {
            return new Listener();
        }
    }

    public static class Listener {
        @RabbitListener(id = TRANSACTIONS_LISTENER, queues = "${queues.transactions}")
        public void receive(SalesTransaction transaction) {
            Logger.getLogger(Listener.class.getName()).log(Level.INFO, "Received tx: {0}", transaction);
        }
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        // this makes the test work, setting it to `true` makes it deadlock
        rabbitTemplate.setChannelTransacted(false);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldBeSentToGateway() throws Exception {
        SalesTransaction savedTransaction = service.saveTransaction(salesTransaction);

        InvocationData invocationData = this.harness.getNextInvocationDataFor(TRANSACTIONS_LISTENER, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        assertNotNull(invocationData);
        assertEquals(salesTransaction, invocationData.getArguments()[0]);
    }
}
```

```
11:02:56.844 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] INFO  org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.DirectMessageListenerContainer - SimpleConsumer [queue=transactions, consumerTag=sgen_1 identity=16ef3497] started
Mar 25, 2019 11:02:57 AM AmqpSalesTransactionGateway send
INFO: Sending transaction: 01a92a56-c93b-4d02-af66-66ef007c2817 w/ status COMPLETED
11:02:57.961 [main] INFO  org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory - Attempting to connect to: [localhost:5672]
11:02:57.972 [main] INFO  org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory - Created new connection: rabbitConnectionFactory.publisher#6d543ec2:0/SimpleConnection@79dd79eb [delegate=amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/, localPort= 56501]

java.lang.AssertionError
    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:86)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:41)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull(Assert.java:712)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull(Assert.java:722)
```

Comment: It's not clear where you are sending the message with the RabbitTemplate but the sent message will not be received by the consumer until the transaction commits.

Comment: `saveTransaction` sends the message and indeed, when the transaction commits the messages gets sent, no deadlock 
The key here is that the test cannot be marked as `@Transactional`, not even with `@Commit`, as the transaction gets committed after the test method finishes, while the listener assertions are verified inside it.

Thank you!

Comment: Consider to use `TransactionTemplate` withing your test-case.

Comment: I'm not sure it's necessary as the transaction gets started anyway when entering `service.saveTransaction(salesTransaction)` and gets committed on method exit.

As far as I understand, for testing this case, simply removing the `@Transactional` annotation from the test is correct.